# How to troubleshoot Azure SQL Database performance issues?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure

I am writing some views on an elastic pool configured Azure SQL DB.  I have a background doing this work in Oracle, but I am seeing things with Azure I don't know how to explain or troubleshoot.

Primarily, I have queries that can take less than a second on Oracle at all times.  But when I run it on Azure for the 1st time, it can take 40-50 seconds.  But then if I run the query again immediately, it is on par with what I see in Oracle.

The query is a simple join of three tables - a model table, an items table, and an attributes table.  A model will have 1:n items, and the item will have 1:n attributes.  I query the model table for a given ID.  So the query is just this:

```
select pa.*
  from ITEM_TABLE ppi, ATTR_TABLE pa, MODEL_TABLE pmc
 where ppi.ITEM_ID = pa.ID
   AND pa.ID_TYPE = 'ITEM'
   AND ppi.MODEL_ID = pmc.MODEL_ID
   AND pmc.PRODUCT_ID = '8675309eeeiine'
```

or if you prefer:

```
select pa.*
  from ITEM_TABLE ppi
       INNER JOIN ATTR_TABLE pa ON (ppi.ITEM_ID = pa.ID AND pa.ID_TYPE = 'ITEM')
       INNER JOIN MODEL_TABLE pmc ON (ppi.MODEL_ID = pmc.MODEL_ID) 
 where pmc.PRODUCT_ID = '8675309eeeiine'
```

The tables in Oracle and Azure are the exact same tables with the same data, same everything. I have made sure to create the same indexes on each DB (plus more on Azure to try and make these queries run at an acceptable performance).

My suspicion is that this is more of an issue with Azure than it is with the queries or the tables or the data.  Could elastic pool explain why the query will run at an acceptable speed only subsequent runs?  Or am I seeing the query store come into play?

More importantly, how can I find out to prove it to the powers that be?

How can I troubleshoot to figure out what causes the query to run so slowly the first time and then so quickly the subsequent runs?

Here is the explain plan from the two DBs for the exact same query (the top one is fast, bottom one is slow on first run) (sorry for two different IDE explain plans, I have TOAD for Oracle but not yet MS SQL)

Here is the Azure explain plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkDdUrSMF

And here is the best I can do for the Oracle explain plan unless someone has a way to share these more easily

```
Plan hash value: 4203126522
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                                | 67991 |    13M|       | 48475   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY            |                                | 67991 |    13M|    16M| 48475   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN               |                                | 67991 |    13M|       | 45474   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN              |                                |  2790 | 78120 |       |   697   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     VIEW                  | index$_join$_004               |   289 |  4046 |       |    60   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN            |                                |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN    | grp_MOD_PROD_ID               |   289 |  4046 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| grp_MOD_MODEL_CONCEPT_ID      |   289 |  4046 |       |    73   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |     VIEW                  | index$_join$_001               | 77844 |  1064K|       |   637   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |      HASH JOIN            |                                |       |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| grp_PROD_ITM_MODEL_CONCEPT_ID | 77844 |  1064K|       |   283   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| grp_PROD_ITM_PROD_ITM_ID      | 77844 |  1064K|       |   242   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL      | grp_ATTRIBUTES                |  4435K|   736M|       | 44736   (1)| 00:00:02 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("PPI"."PRODUCT_ITEM_ID"="PA"."OWNER_ID")
   3 - access("PPI"."MODEL_CONCEPT_ID"="PMC"."MODEL_CONCEPT_ID")
   4 - filter("PMC"."PRODUCT_ID"='123456')
   5 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
   6 - access("PMC"."PRODUCT_ID"='123456')
   9 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  12 - filter("PA"."OWNER_TYPE"='PRODUCT_ITEM')
```

Here are the INDEXes:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--grpAttributes
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [x].[grpAttributes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_grpAttributes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AttributeId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_ATTRNAM_LKP] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [AttributeName] ASC,
    [LookupValue] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_ATTRNAM_VAL_DATE] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [AttributeName] ASC,
    [ValueType] ASC,
    [DateValue] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_ATTRNAM_VAL_NUM] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [AttributeName] ASC,
    [ValueType] ASC,
    [NumberValue] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_OWN_ID_OWN_TYPE] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [OwnerId] ASC,
    [OwnerType] ASC
)
INCLUDE([ParentAttributeId],[AttributeName],[IsApplicable],[OccurrenceIndex],[Locale],[ValueType],[TextValue],[NumberValue],[DateValue],[LookupRowId],[LookupValue],[Sha1],[SortValue],[PiUsageContext],[DiUsageContext],[LocaleWeb]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_OWN_ID_TYPE_ATTRNAM] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [OwnerType] ASC,
    [OwnerId] ASC,
    [AttributeName] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_OWNER_ID_PI_USE_CONTEXT] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [OwnerId] ASC,
    [PiUsageContext] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_OWNER_TYPE] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [OwnerType] ASC
)
INCLUDE([OwnerId],[AttributeName],[OccurrenceIndex],[Locale],[TextValue],[NumberValue],[DateValue],[SortValue]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_ATTR_PARENT_ATTR_ID] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [ParentAttributeId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TEMP_grp_ATTR_ATTRNAM_LKP] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [AttributeName] ASC,
    [LookupValue] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TEMP_grp_ATTR_OWNER_ID_PI_USE_CONTEXT] ON [x].[grpAttributes]
(
    [OwnerId] ASC,
    [PiUsageContext] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--grpProductitems
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE [x].[grpProductItems] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_grpProductItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductItemId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_items_prod_type_base_value] ON [x].[grpProductItems]
(
    [ProductType] ASC,
    [BaseValue] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_PROD_ITEMS_FOD_SALES_CLS_BASE_VAL] ON [x].[grpProductItems]
(
    [FirstOrderableDate] ASC,
    [SalesClass] ASC,
    [BaseValue] ASC
)
INCLUDE([PartNumber],[ModelConceptId]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_PROD_ITM_INV_ITM_ID] ON [x].[grpProductItems]
(
    [InventoryItemId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_PROD_ITM_MODEL_CONCEPT_ID] ON [x].[grpProductItems]
(
    [ModelConceptId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_PROD_ITM_PART_NUMBER] ON [x].[grpProductItems]
(
    [PartNumber] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--grpModelConcepts
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [x].[grpModelConcepts] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_grpModelConcepts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ModelConceptId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_MOD_NAME] ON [x].[grpModelConcepts]
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_grp_MOD_PROD_ID] ON [x].[grpModelConcepts]
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

### PROGRESS UPDATE 2021-09-07

The grpAttributes table has 5.6 million rows in it.  I created a pre-filtered version of the table and added the same indexes to it.  This smaller table has only about 800k records in it.    The query got down to 9 seconds on first runs, a bit faster on second runs.  So it really seems like the size of the data is the issue here.

I also tried creating an index on a view (side note - materialized views would pretty much solve the issue for me, but view indexes are the closest I can find in Azure SQL).  This view uses the full version of the table (the one with 5.6 million rows), but filters out a lot of what I do not need (similar to how I created the smaller version of the table).  Querying this view in place of the table in my original query got down to 2 seconds.  But that has not been a reliable query. At times the SQL optimizer will use the index on the view, but then if I incorporate it into more complex queries, it seems like sometimes the sql optimizer will not use the view index.

So it still seems to come back to the size of the data though.  Is this expected with Azure SQL?  Does it just become not performant at certain data sizes?  How do I get an understanding of such limits?  Could it have to do with how the DB is configured?

### PROGRESS UPDATE 2021-09-09

I met with the platform owners for the Azure DB we use.  Their response was that essentially I am on my own because the issue is with the Microsoft product (Azure DB), and not their platform. Setting aside the reasoning there, this gets me back to figuring out why this simple 3 table join I am trying is so terribly slow on the Azure DB.  Can anyone help me with that?  The explain plan is pasted above. I really need help figuring out what the deal is that. The platform owners I spoke with mentioned it could be something to do with the structure of the data, but I keep coming back to the fact that Oracle gives me the same explain plan and has the same indexes, data, structure, etc, and the performance difference there is huge.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? Your title says Azure SQL Database, which is a SQL Server contained database cloud solution, and then you talk about Oracle *and* tag [[tag:mysql]]. Just tag what are *really* using.

Comment: In your edit: your two queries are not remotely equivalent.  The first is forcing an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: The first query uses ANSI-89 `INNER JOIN`'s, the second ANSI-92 `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s; they aren't equivalent. If you wanted to express an `OUTER JOIN` back in the 80's you would have used `*=` or `=*`; neither of which are supported in SQL Server (they were deprecated in 2008, and removed in 2012).

Comment: Thanks, fixed, I think.

Comment: Neither of those query plans look particularly reasonable to me.  What indexes exist and what does the data distribution look like?  I'd guess `product_id` is unique in `model_table`, that `model_id` is indexed in `item_table`, that you'd need to read a small fraction of `item_table` to get all the items for a particular model, that (`id`, `id_type`)  is indexed in `attr_table` and that both optimizers would do a pretty simple nested loop with `model_table` as the driving table.

Comment: Neither optimizer picks this approach so I'm guessing that you're either missing indexes or that you've got some non-obvious data distributions that the optimizers are aware of that we're not which explains why both databases are doing full scans on `attr_table`.

Comment: We need to see full index definitions, and please share the query plan (preferably actual rather than estimated) via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @mkohanek, which model of Azure SQL Database are you using ?  It is serverless ?

Comment: I am trying to get the type of DB, but this is a DB on a platform my company purchased, so I have to go to the vendor when I need those types of answers, and it takes time.  @Charlieface thanks for the link, it has been helpful with troubleshooting on my own.  Here is the actual plan (returned 232,956 rows in 1:04.  On Oracle this takes 7 seconds) : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkDdUrSMF

Comment: indexes added as well @JustinCave.  The one you mentioned for the attributes table is there.  It has a lot of INCLUDE columns due to me experimenting with things, but I have tried it without with similar results.  INCLUDE in an index is a new concept for me

Comment: It's going to be difficult for you to troubleshoot if you can't see the Azure configuration. If it is serverless as @RobertoHernandez mentioned, that would explain it, and it has nothing to do with table size or indexes.

Comment: If it is "elastic pool" as you mentioned then you are sharing resources with dozens of other databases, so again, it could simply be lack of resources or resourcing conflicts with queries in other databases. If your vendor is supplying you this solution, they need to come to the party for performance tuning, you can't do it without the Azure configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I have a meeting with the vendor in two days actually. I plan to show them the performance of the queries in Oracle vs Azure while everything else I can control is at parity. If you have any suggestions on the kinds of questions or information I should prepare for this meeting I would love to hear it. Azure SQL is new to me, so I am not entirely sure what is relevant. I can use my Oracle background to help me out there, but I don't know what I don't know when it comes to Azure. I believe it is serverless compute too, I am fairly certain I remember them saying so

Comment: Serverless is not elastic. They are two different things. Serverless has a warm up time so I'd say this is your issue. I would avoid bringing Oracle into it, it'll just cloud the issue. Instead I suggest you have a reproducible example ready, also pick a specific time that the issue occurs and the vendor will be able to tell you if the serverless was starting up at that time. Serverless is theretically cheaper, so you'll need to consider if you want to pay more for better performance.

Comment: It is elastic pool. Apparently we are hitting 100% resource allocation for these queries. From what the platform owners tell me, the resource allocation is sufficient for other very large customers, and so it must be an issue of table structure. How can I get insight into what could be changed on these tables to improve performance, especially when the explain plan is already so simplified?

Comment: Changing the select from pa.* to pa.textValue made the query take less than 10 seconds. That made a huge difference.  I don't know why that makes such a difference but it did. My final query needs more than just that one column and is still slow-ish.  So would adding INCLUDES () to all my indexes and include the columns I need help with that?